# how to create a login API in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a web application which is completely written in `node js`.
All the functionalities and the web UI has been completed.

What happening is, I am able to hit the services API without logging into the application.  It is like you can use the services without logging to app.

Can anyone tell me how I can create a login API so that until the user logs in, it cant use the services?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to use `passportjs`, great library to implement log in strategies, and really well documented. I hope that it would be help full.

http://passportjs.org/

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom middleware where you check whether the user is logged in or not, And then redirect accordingly (to the login page).

Something like below, (**I used `express-session` here**)

```
var isLoggedIn = function(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.username) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
}
```

And then use it in the following form with your `API`.

```
app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/views/home.html'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From what you have written I understnad that you have written an API using nodeJS. As others have stated, passportJS is the right tool for this but it comes with many strategies. Try using this one: https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt. is intended to be used to secure RESTful endpoints without sessions.